# Put images at the top of footer

Tags: html, css

I am a novice to learning HTML and CSS. I want to add images at the top of footer. How can I achieve it.

I have the footer created and the images in one line. But somehow i don't know how to place them at top of the footer. The HTML and CSS are below. Using stylesheet from bootstrap.

```
    <id ="image">
    <a href="#"><img src="images1.png" align="left" style="width:20%;height:200px;margin:auto;padding:75px;" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images2.png" align="left" style="width:20%;height:200px;margin:auto;padding:75px;"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images3.png" align="left" style="width:20%;height:200px;margin:auto;padding:75px;"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images4.png" align="left" style="width:20%;height:200px;margin:auto;padding:75px;"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images5.png" align="left" style="width:20%;height:200px;margin:auto;padding:75px;"></a>
   </id>
<footer id="footer">
 <div class="container">
    <p>some text for the footer</p>
 </div>
</footer>
```

The CSS used is below.

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
#image {
position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVeQyb

```
<div id="images">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x80.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x80.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x80.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x80.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x80.png"></a>
   </div>

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
#images {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

#images a{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: the images i am trying to put should be **just above** the footer.
can i somehow use **div** inside the footer, so that, they appear just above it ?

Comment: `<id ="image">` is incorrect, you need to use a valid HTML element, so I changed to a div. When image was changed to a div, it wasn't positioned relative to any parent, so it took the normal flow of the document. I changed so it was also absolutely positioned it and offset the value to be above the footer. Really, there should be no need to use positioning like this for a footer. You content above the footer would push the footer to the bottom using the normal document flow, however I just wanted to solve your particular issue.

Answer (score -1):

One method would be to position your images absolute as well. Code below:

```
<div id="image">
    <a href="#"><img src="images1.png" align="left" style="width:20%;height:200px;margin:auto;padding:75px;"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images2.png" align="left" style="width:20%;height:200px;margin:auto;padding:75px;"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images3.png" align="left" style="width:20%;height:200px;margin:auto;padding:75px;"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images4.png" align="left" style="width:20%;height:200px;margin:auto;padding:75px;"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images5.png" align="left" style="width:20%;height:200px;margin:auto;padding:75px;"></a>
</div>
<footer id="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p>some text for the footer</p>
    </div>
</footer>

#image {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

---

2nd method: Place your images inside the footer, in this case you need to change the footer height, since it is absolute positioned.

3rd method: Simply leave the footer in the content flow. Remove the absolute positioning.